# Volume of a sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Using cylindrical coordinates, find the volume of the smaller part of a sphere with a radius $r$ that intersect with a plane at a distance of $h$ from the center of the sphere

I understand that the limits of integrations are: $0 \leq  \phi\leq 2\pi$ and $h\leq z \leq r$ but how do I find the upper limit of the radius? (the envelope of the sphere)

Comment: Not clear what you mean. $\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$?

Comment: @almagest the radius goes from $0$ to the envelope of the sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vol=$\int_h^r\pi(r^2-z^2)dz=\pi(r^2z-z^3/3)|_h^r=\pi(2r^3-r^2h+h^3)/3$

Comment: where did $\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$ came from?

Comment: Sorry, typo for $\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$.

Comment: so it basically pitagoras?